# Event with return value

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm using the `dart:async` library to do some data processing. I'm adding objects to a `StreamController` and another module is listening to the stream. Now I want, that the other module is returning a result of the processing back to the `add` call (as a future).

Here is some example code that should illustrate what I want to do (It doesn't work, because the add method doesn't return a future):

```dart
final controller = new StreamController();

controller.stream.listen((a) {
  // Do something with a, after that return something:
  return 42;
});

final aFuture = controller.add(new A());

aFuture.then((result) {
  // result == 42
});
```

Is something like this possible with `dart:async`, another library, or do I need to write my own classes?

PS: An alternative would be the following, but it would be 'more complicated' to use that a simple return:

```dart
final controller = new StreamController();

controller.stream.listen((container) {
  // Do something with container.a, after that return something:

  container.completer.complete(42);
});


final completer = new Completer();
controller.add(new Container(new A(), completer));

completer.future.then((result) {
  // result == 42
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wrapper around the StreamController like:

```dart
class StreamControllerWrapper{
  MessageBox mb;
  StreamController controller;
  StreamControllerWrapper(this.controller){
    mb = new MessageBox();
    controller.stream.listen((a) {
      var replyTo = a['replyTo'];
      // Do something with a, after that return something:
      replyTo.add(42);
    });
  }
  Future add(msg){
    Completer c = new Completer();
    mb.stream.listen((reply){
      c.complete(reply);
    });
    controller.add({'content':msg, 'replyTo':mb.sink});
    return c.future;
  }
}
```

And then invoke the behavior like this:

```dart
final controllerWrapper = new StreamControllerWrapper(new StreamController());
controllerWrapper.add(new A())
  .then((result){
    print(result);
  });
```

Comment: That is similar to the second way I thought about, but not what I'm looking for...